# Ways of Listing SQL Error?

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to list all the errors of sql server, i am using the below method

```
 USE MASTER

    GO

    SELECT * FROM SYS.MESSAGES
```

is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You could just type "SQL Server error messages" in google, like I did, and go to the [official documentation...](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored procedures and triggers in your database then you can create a separate table to capture the errors using exeception handling like the below.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE Prc_procedurename
AS
  BEGIN
      BEGIN try
          PRINT 'enter your code here'
      END try

      BEGIN catch
          INSERT INTO ERROR_LOG
                      ([DBname],
                       [ProcedureName],
                       [ErrorNumber],
                       [ErrorLine],
                       [ErrorMessage])
          SELECT Db_name(),
                 CONVERT(NVARCHAR(300), Object_name(@@PROCID)),
                 CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), Error_number()),
                 CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), Error_line()),
                 Error_message()
      END catch
  END
```

or else you simply need to get the list of errors then use this

```
SELECT message_id,
       severity,
       text
FROM   sys.messages
WHERE  language_id = 1033;
```

Comment: Note that TRY/CATCH fails to catch a wide variety of errors.